# Apache Virtual Host Setup on Centos for Zend Framework 3

Tags: apache, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-framework3

I am newbie to zf3 and have extracted the ZF3 Skeleton Application from GitHub into location `/var/www/html/zf2-tutorial` and had installed successfully to get the zf3 home page from URL `https://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/zf2-tutorial/public`

While going through the tutorial i found i have to set up a virtual host to access the site like `zf2-tutorial.localhost` so i followed the steps and making a `zf2-tutorial.conf` file under `/etc/httpd/conf.d` folder .

zf2-tutorial.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName https://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/zf2-tutorial
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/zf2-tutorial/public
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
<Directory /var/www/html/zf2-tutorial/public>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I also edited my `/etc/hosts` file to add

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
xxx.xxx.xx.xx  xxx.xxx.xx.xx/zf2-tutorial
```

All i want i want to access the zf3 home page by accessing the URL

```
https://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/zf2-tutorial/
```

I am using `httpd-2.4.6-67.el7.centos.6.x86_64`

The Tutorial Link https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/skeleton-application/

Comment: If you want to access the site via. an ip address (which is what I assume the xxx.xxx.xx.xx represents), then you don't need a virtual host. What you've setup won't do anything as both the server name and hosts file entry need to be a hostname, not a full URL.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the new `zf2-tutorial.conf` file inside your https.conf file?

```
# include zf2 tutorial host file
Include /etc/httpd/conf.d/zf2-tutorial.conf
```

Or is there a wildcard to that path inside your config?

```
Include /etc/httpd/conf.d/*.conf
```

Comment: `IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf`